# Thread wait for Signal in a loop

Tags: c, multithreading, gcc, pthreads

I'm a newbie in C. I want to create a program with two threads that will send signals (SIGUSR1 and SIGNUSR2) in a loop and four threads that will waiting for these signals and handle them.

I understood that sending the signal I need to do: `kill(getpid,SIGUSR1);` but howto I create four threads that will wait for the signal? the signal is registered to a specific function. How four threads will wait for the same signal?

Can I have other threads checking the type of signal also (without stopping the signal to reach the other threads)?

Thanks.

---

**Update:** 
I'm trying to have four threads waiting for signals, when the two threads send the signals, the threads don't know which thread will catch the signal. I don't want to specify the thread id that will receive the signal.

When using `pthread_kill()` I need to specify the thread id (which I'm trying not to do).

Comment: is there a reason you have to use signals (for what looks like synchronisation issue)?

Comment: What do you mean by a "random process"? You can set up signal masks per thread to only allow the signal to reach certain threads, and then use `kill` to let the kernel pick an arbitrary, random thread to receive the signal. Or you could actively enumerate all your threads, use a random number generator to chose from among them, and send a directed signal.

Comment: @KerrekSB, can I send a signal to two processes at the same time, and which ever is free will handle the signal? Or can I create few processes which belong to the same group and send the signal to the entire group?

Comment: You can send a signal to the entire process, and precisely *one* thread, which must not be blocking the thread, and randomly chosen, receives the signal. The signal is guaranteed to be delivered at most once.

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** This answer is probably partly useless. You should use `pthread_kill` to send signals to a specific thread. I'll leave it around in case someone finds something in it, though.

---

On Linux, threads cannot be handled with `kill`, since `kill` will send the signal to *any random* thread that isn't blocking the signal.

Instead, you want the [`tgkill`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/tgkill.2.html) system call, which targets a specific thread. Which thread? You find out with the system call [`gettid`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/gettid.2.html).

Unfortunately, glibc doesn't provide wrappers for those two system calls. No problem, you can write those yourself:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

pid_t gettid()
{
    return syscall(SYS_gettid);
}

int tgkill(int sig, pid_t pgid, pid_t tid)
{
    return syscall(SYS_tkill, sig, pgid, tid);
}
```

The first argument of `tgkill` is the signal, as for `kill`. The second is the *thread group id*, which is the same as the *process id* of your process (obtainable with `getpid`). The last argument is the kernel thread id, which you obtain with `gettid`, and which also makes up the directories in `/proc/<pid>/task/` on Linux.

Finally, you need to be able to wait for a signal to arrive. You do this by blocking the signal in the thread with [`pthread_sigmask`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_sigmask.3.html) and then using [`sigwaitinfo` or `sigtimedwait`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigwaitinfo.2.html):

```
// block signal
sigset_t newset, oldset;
sigemptyset(&nweset);
sigaddset(&newset, SIGUSR1);
pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, &newset, &oldset);

// wait
sigwaitinfo(&newset, NULL);

// restore previous signal mask
pthread_sigmast(SIG_SETMASK, &oldset, NULL);
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. But do I specify the thread I'm sending the signal to? how do I know which thread will catch it? Also, how do I send the signal in a loop?

Comment: @Mike: By using `gettid` in the desired thread! I'm not sure if you can get the thread id of a *different* thread, though. You could enumerate `/proc/<pid>/task/` and exclude your own thread id to see what all the others are. Or make each new thread send a signal back (check the docs, you can add data in the siginfo part).

Comment: Just retaining the IDs of the threads when you create them is another obvious option.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths: How? I don't think they're reported in any way.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths: (Unless you give up on pthreads and use `clone()` directly. Phrrr.)

Comment: @KerrekSB: Not sure I follow - the first argument to `pthread_create()` gets modified to contain the ID of the new thread, so you can just keep track of that value. Or are we talking two different kinds of IDs, here?

Comment: @KerrekSB: OK, perhaps I should read more carefully, the thread ID you're talking about is not the same thread ID that `pthread_create()` uses. Setting up a data structure to map the two, and have each thread update it as it begins would be workable, or just use `pthread_kill()`.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths: Right, that's a completely unrelated kind of ID... `pthread_kill` may indeed be a much better answer, so you should post that.

Comment: @KerrekSB: I had a go, but I wasn't happy enough with the draft I had to post a proper answer. The meat of the question seemed to be about waiting for the signals rather than sending them, which I think you have covered.

Comment: Thanks guys for the conversion here. @KerrekSB, I'm asking this because in 'tgkill' I need to specify the thread id. However, tgkill is asking for thread id, and I don't know which thread will catch the signal.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths, the question is all about undertanding signal between threads in C. But I still not clear on how to have two threads running in a loop and sending random signals.

Comment: @Mike: Maybe you could update your question for more clarity, it's not clear to me for instance whether you want to send a signal and have all the threads handle it at once, or one random thread to handle it, or a specific thread to handle it. If you could be more specific about what you're trying to accomplish it would be easier to suggest a good approach.

Comment: @Mike: One more Q, do you *have* to use signals, here? In general, mixing signals with threads is a pretty bad idea, an entirely different approach is likely to be better.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths, Can I use processes and signals?

Comment: @Mike: Sure, you *can* use signals and threads, it's just not usually a great idea. Seems like threads and simple condition variables might work for your example. For instance, what do you want to do if a thread gets a signal while it's in the middle of responding to a previous one? Just ignore it until it's free? Seems exactly what queuing up behind one or two condition variables would do for you, only simpler. Signals can be a bit of a blunt instrument.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths, it's an assignment to learn about processes, threads and signals.

Answer (score 0):

I really wouldn't recommend using SIGUSR signals for thread synchronization. If you want pthreads to wait on a signal, I'd look at the man pages for `pthread_cond_signal`